# Solve the recurrence relation $T(n) = c(T(n/c) + 1), T(1) = 1$, by finding an expression for $T(n)$ in big-Oh notation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

I'm a complete beginner at this, and was having trouble with this problem.

looking at  $T(n) = c(T(n/c) + 1)$. I'm pretty sure its in the form of

f(n) = af(n/b) + Cnd

I think the master theorem can be used to get the answer, but I'm not sure how to get the values to compare a to $b^{d}$

Here is what I know

a is the number of subproblems

n/b is the subproblem size

Cnd is the time to be spend during each recursion level (C is a constant)

I'm not sure how to apply this, or if it's the right solution.

Comment: This looks like a great break down, but I really not very experienced in this. I'm having a lot of trouble following what your doing. You said to think of the inputs (n) in the form of $c^{k}$ , I see you do the replacing, but then I lose you when you put it equal to $c^2T(c^{k-2})+c+1 ... = c^kT(1)+1+c+c^2+...+c^{k-1}$. Also how come you let T(1) = a?

Comment: One last thing, since it's in its general form how can i found the expression in Big-Oh notation? Orignally I was going to use the master theorem to compare a and $b^{d}$ but now I'm not sure

Comment: Once you have the general form, you look for the term that grows the fastest. That is your big O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about inputs of the form $c^k$. $$T(c^k)=cT(c^{k-1})+c=c^2T(c^{k-2})+c^2+c=\;...= c^kT(1)+c+c^2+c^3+...+c^k$$ 
$$T(c^k)=\frac{c\cdot c^k-1}{c-1}+c^kT(1)$$

If we want this function to be continuous, we note that $$T(n)=T(c^{\log_cn})=\frac{cn-1}{c-1}+T(1)n$$

If we let $a=T(1)+\frac 1{c-1}$ be an arbitrary constant, we get $$T(n)=an-\frac1{c-1}$$

This is the general form of the recursion. To find the specific form given your constraint, we substitute $T(1)=1$ into our equation for $a$, getting $a=1+\frac 1{c-1}=\frac c{c-1}$. So, the final solution is $$T(n)=\frac{c\cdot n-1}{c-1}$$

And, this function has complexity of $O(n)$ as it is a linear function.